# Elasticsearch service from docker image does not connect to webapp or kibana

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, elixir, ecto

I have a docker-compose.yml file which declares webapp, postgres database, a two node elasticsearch, and a kibana container.

```
version: '3'
services:
  webapp:
    build:
      context: ../../../
      dockerfile: config/docker/dev/Dockerfile-dev
    container_name: MyWebApp-dev
    image: 'localhost:443/123'
    ports:
      - "4000:4000"
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - db
      - elasticsearch
      - kibana
    links:
      - db
      - elasticsearch
      - kibana
  db:
    image: postgres:10
    container_name: db
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=user
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
      - POSTGRES_DB=mine_dev
  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.0.1
    container_name: elasticsearch
    environment:
      - node.name=elasticsearch
      - discovery.seed_hosts=es02
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=elasticsearch,es02
      - cluster.name=docker-cluster
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - esdata01:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
      - 9300:9300
    networks:
      - esnet
  es02:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.0.1
    environment:
      - node.name=es02
      - discovery.seed_hosts=elasticsearch
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=elasticsearch,es02
      - cluster.name=docker-cluster
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - esdata02:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    networks:
      - esnet

  kibana:
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:7.0.1
    ports:
      - "5601:5601"
    container_name: kibana

volumes:
  esdata01:
    driver: local
  esdata02:
    driver: local

networks:
  esnet:
```

They all build successfully, but kibana cannot get a live connection to elasticsearch

```
kibana           | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2019-05-08T23:36:13Z","tags":["status","plugin:searchprofiler@7.0.1","error"],"pid":1,"state":"red","message":"Status changed from red to red - No Living connections","prevState":"red","prevMsg":"Unable to connect to Elasticsearch."}

kibana           | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2019-05-09T00:02:46Z","tags":["warning","elasticsearch","admin"],"pid":1,"message":"No living connections"}
```

and the index "products" cannot be created with elixir/ecto mix

```
MyWebApp-dev |   (elixir) lib/calendar/datetime.ex:537: DateTime.to_unix/2
MyWebApp-dev |   (elasticsearch) lib/elasticsearch/indexing/index.ex:287: Elasticsearch.Index.build_name/1
MyWebApp-dev |   (elasticsearch) lib/elasticsearch/indexing/index.ex:31: Elasticsearch.Index.hot_swap/2
MyWebApp-dev |   (elasticsearch) lib/mix/elasticsearch.build.ex:86: Mix.Tasks.Elasticsearch.Build.build/3
MyWebApp-dev | 
MyWebApp-dev | ** (Mix) Index products could not be created.
MyWebApp-dev | 
MyWebApp-dev |     %HTTPoison.Error{id: nil, reason: :econnrefused}
```

All the while, I can connect to the elasticsearch server:

```
A68MD-PRO:~# curl http://localhost:9200/_cat/health
1557359160 23:46:00 docker-cluster green 2 2 2 1 0 0 0 0 - 100.0%
```

Even from the container inside, curling yields:

```
A68MD-PRO:~# docker exec elasticsearch curl http://elasticsearch:9200/_cat/health
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100    66  100    66    0     0   6969      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  7333
1557373042 03:37:22 docker-cluster green 2 2 2 1 0 0 0 0 - 100.0%
```

Does anyone know what this problem is about and how to solve it?

Update: If I do

```
docker exec -it MyWebApp-dev curl -XPUT 'http://elasticsch:9200/something/example/1' -d ' { "type": "example", "quantity": 2 }' -H'Content-Type: application/json'
```

it works perfectly well. So it must have something to do with httpoison, I think.

Comment: can you please update the kibana settings with `network.host: 0.0.0.0` ?

Comment: As an environment variable ? Standard ones are :

Comment: server.name
 

kibana

server.host
 

"0"

elasticsearch.hosts
 

http://elasticsearch:9200

xpack.monitoring.ui.container.elasticsearch.enabled
 

true

Comment: Just changed the server.host to "0.0.0.0", to no avail.

Comment: And to be frank, the problem with not being able to create an index is far more important than the problem with kibana. I just mentioned it because I think they are related.

Answer (score 0):

the elaticsearch containers are on a different docker network than the kibana container.

Please verify this network configuration:

```
networks:
  - esnet
```

Remove it for the elastic nodes or apply the very same network config for kibana.

Comment: Does that also apply to the webapp container (again, that is the more important question in this context)?

Comment: In my opinion it does not. the elasticstack don´t need to be on the same network as the application as long the components are reachable. in this case via the "links" configuration for the webapp